# How to do a query like "SELECT DISTINCT(HOSTNAME) from *" in Couchbase on Python

Tags: python, mysql, couchbase, nosql

I've just started using Couchbase on Python, this is my first time using a non SQL database.  I am trying to port some code over.  I had an old SQL query that selected unique hostnames from a table.  How would I code that query in Python for Couchbase?  In my Couchbase design the hostname is part of a JSON document, of which there are many "rows".

Thank you,
Virgil.

Answer (score 1):

If you have stored each hostname in a different JSON document in Couchbase then you can select it by using [N1QL](http://docs.couchbase.com/prebuilt/n1ql/n1ql-dp3/):

```
SELECT DISTINCT hostname FROM mybucket
```

If you have one JSON document storing all hostnames in the array, then you can select it like this (using [N1QL](http://docs.couchbase.com/prebuilt/n1ql/n1ql-dp3/)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT myhostnames[0].hostname FROM mybucket
```

e.g. each JSON doc like this:

```
{
"myhostnames": [
        {
          "hostname": "host1"
        },
        {
          "hostname": "host2"
        }
      ]
}
```

also see [N1QL tutorial](http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial)